# Method specific logging

Tags: unit-testing, logging, junit, junit4, performance

Environment: JUnit 4, JDK 6
I would like to log all test names (annotated with @Test) and figure out the amount of time taken to execute each tests executed by JUnit in a standard J2SE environment.

Should I rely on in-built JDK logging Logger.entering / exiting with System.currentTimeInMillis or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the XML files JUnit produces?
They contain the tests run (classname & method name) and the time they took to run.

[Example XML document](http://junitpdfreport.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/junitpdfreport/src/resources/examples/testresults/TEST-net.cars.engine.DemareurTest.xml?revision=1.8&view=markup)